# I want to restore or replace the win 10. My question is how do I do it?

Tags: software-uninstall

OK, win 7 is done, so I upgraded to win 10 on my HP6644Y desktop, (have win 10 on a laptop and am satisfied). After reading here about linux distro's I decided to try Ubuntu. downloaded it and supposedly set it up to dual boot with win 10. Computer booted into a ubuntu menu with choices for win 10, ok, I guess I can live with that.
Decided I was not impressed with the ubuntu so I attempted to remove it.
It would then only boot to a grub screen.
Finally got the ubuntu restored. Now I want to restore or replace the win 10. My question is how do I do it?

Comment: Easiest way is to re install Windows 10. You can create a recovery disk image on a pendrive and use that to re install. This will wipe you whole disk and setup Win 10. If you are worried about the data then I suggest backing up first.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to replace the harddisk (SSD) with a new one and install Windows 10 then. This way you always have the choice to switch back.

If you connect your old disk to an USB SATA adapter you also can copy your data.